# Algolia instantsearch.js callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, algolia, instantsearch.js

I am using Algolia **instantsearch.js** as my site search.

The setup process was rather easy and straightforward, including .js and .css files, creating templates and then create one more .js file with `app()` function for setting up my app (appId, apiKey, indexName) and widgets.

What I need is a function that will execute each time a search function ran, preferably right after the hits are shown.

Maybe there is a **widget** for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen the `render` event like described [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/instantsearch/js/?language=js#events), it's an event triggered once all widgets have been rendered:

```
var search = instantsearch({...});
search.on('render', function() {
   // FIXME
});
```

You could also create a [custom widget](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/create-your-own-widgets/js/) and do a specific action in the `render` method.