# Algolia Instantsearch - add a callback after results are displayed?

Tags: algolia

I have an application that allows users to search for artwork and build their own portfolios.  I'd like to show whether a piece of artwork that is returned in an algolia search is contained within the users portfolio, but I can't seem to find a way to make a callback once results are displayed to the user.

is it possible to add a callback to the search results?

Comment: You need to provide more details, what language are you using on what platform? Can you show a code sample?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry.  First time ever posting on SO.  Been a long-time reader.  I'll take note and do better next time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algolia instantsearch.js callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640641/algolia-instantsearch-js-callback-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you use [instantsearch.js library](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/) for displaying the results.

Then there are two ways on how to achieve what you want.

**1) Use `transformData` parameter of [`hits` widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#hits)**

The parameter takes callback and passes results there. So you can modify the results before it gets displayed - you can add a new parameter based on if the record is the one which should be highlighted.

Example:

```
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits-container',
    templates: {
      item: itemTemplate
    }, 
    transformData: {
      allItems: function (results) {
        console.log(results);

        // Modify results

        return results;
      }
    }
  })
);
```

**2) Use [custom widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#custom-widgets) to hook a render callback**

You can write a simple custom widget where you specify only the `render` option:

```
search.addWidget({
  render: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

In `data` parameter you'll get all information about the search, inluding helper, last state and the latest results.

Both approaches you can see live in small jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JanPetr/g54hzrzp/

Comment: This was perfect.  The transformData parameter was exactly what I was looking for.  It allowed me to update the results so I could process it in the view.

Comment: In v2 of instant-search, use 'item' instead of 'allItems'. https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/widgets-common-api.html#transformdata

Comment: An alternative to #2: `search.on('render', function() {
    console.log('Algolia has just rendered the DOM.');
    myCallback();
});` The only caveat is that no data is passed to it.